# Wrong signature from ATMEGA8-16PU after setting fuses with avrdude

Tags: arduino, atmega, icsp

I am lost in loading bootloader for Arduino Single Sided on ATMEGA8-16PU.
Here is my problem.

1. I [made the Arduino Single Sided V3](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardSerialSingleSided3.)
2. Placed ATMEGA8-16PU in the board and attached it to the [Parallel Programmer](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/ParallelProgrammer) and attached external 9V battery.
3. Accessed the controller using `avrdude` using command line and it returned correct signature `0x1e9307`.
4. I executed this command `avrdude -p atmega8 -c dapa -P lpt1 -U lock:w:0xff:m` it worked well. Everything was fine till this point and controller returning correct signature.
5. Then this `avrdude -p atmega8 -c dapa -P lpt1 -U hfuse:w:0xca:m -U lfuse:w:0xdf:m` and suddenly after execution of this command controller was returning wrong signature `0x000012`.

What is wrong? I cannot go further? Why it is returning the wrong signature?

But I noticed something odd, controller was not returning `0xffffff` it means it is not bricked, its alive and hence returning signature whatever it is.

Maybe the default baud-rate of programmer is not matching anymore with the baud-rate change in controller for different clock source.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at:

http://frank.circleofcurrent.com/fusecalc/fusecalc.php?chip=atmega8&LOW=DF&HIGH=CA&EXTENDED=FF&LOCKBIT=FF

I see that you've turned off all of the CKSEL bits, which seems to select "external clock". Supplying a square wave to XTAL1 on your AVR might work.

Comment: Thanks @Joby, please can you explain little bit more how can i do that?

Comment: Also can you please explain that why the controller is returning 0x000012 this weird signature. If i did not provided the proper clock it should not return any signature at all.

Comment: I'm afraid, I've never done it before. I'd try a fresh microcontroller and more care with the fuse settings. You could ask on avrfreaks, they're a good specialist resource for AVR questions